# ReplaceAll not replacing all in recursive function

Tags: javascript, replace, replaceall

I'm using a recursive function that takes a template string like this:

```
<div class='${classes}'>
```

and replaces the template literal placeholder ${classes} with valued from an object that looks like this:

```
{ classes: 'bg-${color} text-${color}', color: 'blue' }
```

Something to note here is that within the object, there is more template string nesting, hence the reason for the recursive function.

The thing I cannot work out is why the replace all function is only replacing the 1st instance of ${color}, and leaving the second undefined.

Working snippet below:

```js
function buildTemplate(string) {
  var matched = false;
  string = string.replaceAll(/\$\{(.*?)\}/g, function (match, key) {
    if (match) {
      matched = true;
    }
    const selection = selectors[key];
    delete selectors[key];
    return selection;
  });
  if (matched) {
    string = buildTemplate(string);
  }
  console.log(string);
}

let templateString = "<div class='${classes}'>";
const selectors = { classes: 'bg-${color} text-${color}', color: 'blue' }
buildTemplate(templateString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting `selectors`, when you need it twice.
Remove line;

```
// delete selectors[key]
```

or `selection` get assigned nothing

No need to delete anything when it's an object that is accessed through a key.

Comment: Hmm yeah I'm not sure if there's really any other solution than removing the delete selectors. I'm using it for another part of my function, but perhaps I need to manage that a different way to have this work...

Comment: Use an array then.
`const selection = selectors[key].shift()`  

`const selectors = { classes: ['bg-${color} text-${color}'], color: ['blue', 'red'] }`